# Regular Expression for Finding URL (ending with FLV/flv)

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to get all instances of http://someurl/somefile.flv within a HTML file.  Extension must not be case sensitive.

I currently use the following simple regular expression that I use in Javascript:

```
var rePattern = new RegExp(
    "(http://.*.flv)",
    "gi"
  );
```

It has it's flaws though, especially if there is a URL and somewhere further in the file you have something mentioning FLV.

I've found various regular expressions that check for URLs, etc but I cannot correctly modify them to just search for FLV links.

Answer (score 1):

```
/http:\/\/[\S]+?\.flv/g

document.body.innerHTML.match(/http:\/\/[\S]+?\.flv/g)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were doing this, my regexp would look something like:

```
http:\/\/(.+)\.(.+)\.flv
```

I escaped my special characters, as you should do. Specifically, the two slashes, and the period right before "flv". Your regexp would incorrectly match "http://123flv" which I'm sure you don't want. My version also requires a top-level-domain, e.g., example.com. Yours would have matched http://example/x.flv which clearly isn't a valid URL. Notice, also, how I use the + instead of *, to ensure that one or more characters is present.

Hope this helps.

-tjw

Comment: is there a way to force the detection of the .flv.

as an example, it incorrectly pics up a flv file in http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-8SJTDyIZjM

it matches:

http://www.youtube.com/get_video?video_id=-8SJTDyIZjM&t=vjVQa1PpcFPIwBLpAL6uZSMvGDTwFnd9L__AQoEBQpA=&fmt=18" class="yt-button yt-button-urgent" style="width:100px">Download (MP4)Download (3GP)Download (FLV

Comment: sorry, that is:

[code]http://www.youtube.com/get_video?video_id=-8SJTDyIZjM&t=vjVQa1PpcFPIwBLpAL6uZSMvGDTwFnd9L__AQoEBQpA=&fmt=18" class="yt-button yt-button-urgent" style="width:100px">Download (MP4)Download (3GP)Download (FLV[/code]

Comment: Oops.  I didn't realise I had a plugin that adds additional code into that page, so you won't see it.

This is the code that gets picked up.

<pre>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/get_video?video_id=-8SJTDyIZjM&amp;t=vjVQa1PpcFPIwBLpAL6uZSMvGDTwFnd9L__AQoEBQpA=" class="yt-button yt-button-urgent" style="width:100px"><span>Download (FLV)</span> </a>
</pre>

Answer (score 0):

http://[^\"\'<>{}\s]{6,255}(?<=.flv)

Comment: do you mind explaining this one? As far as i can read, it matches http://   then it matches from non-url-weird chars that appear from 6 to 255 (max in url) times, then there is vortex (wtf is ?<=) then .flv. But I tested it, and if I put less than 6 chars in the main part of the URL it works as well..

Comment: @MarceloRamires (?<= is a look-behind expression to make sure the pattern ended with .flv. It's more efficient that the (.*)? style thing because it happens once the previous expression is evaluated. 'if I put less than 6 chars...' You're not counting the .flv part. Make it a bigger number.

Comment: I get this error:

SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /http://[^"'<>{}s]{6,255}(?<=.flv)/: Invalid group

Using: var rePattern = new RegExp("http:\/\/[^\"\'<>{}\s]{6,255}(?<=.flv)","gi");